# Bootstrap 5 - Uncaught TypeError: Popper__namespace.createPopper is not a function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am using Django to serve web pages.

- I am trying to make sure I am able to download all the resources necessary to make the webpage function as intended for **offline use** (as in one of those resources could be unavailable for my client to request, so I want to be able to have my server serve those files, or if I decide to run a copy of the site on a Raspberry Pi on localhost or something of the sort). One of which is bootstrap 5.
- I am trying to use their **dropdown menu feature**... according to their docs:

  > Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper. Popper isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.
- Because I am keen to find a solution, I have inserted a bunch of `<script>` tags trying to rule out the problem... maybe it's a bad idea.

What can I try next?

```
{% load static %}

<html class="w-100 h-100">
<head>
    <title>
        Fonts
    </title>

    <!--Important meta tags-->
    <!--Cancel zoom for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <!--example:-->
    <!--href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}"-->

    <!--theme-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="{% static 'Pages/favicons/CES.png' %}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Pages/css/main.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/js/main.js' %}"></script>

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!--bootstrap related-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <style>
{% if fonts %}
{% for font in fonts %}
        @font-face
        {
{% if font.font_family %}
            font-family: "{{font.font_family}}";
{% endif %}
{% if font.path %}
            src: url("{{font.path}}");
{% endif %}
        }
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    </style>

</head>
<body class="m-0 p-0 w-100 h-100">

    <button id="fonts" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Fonts</span>
    </button>
    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="fonts">
{% if fonts%}
{% for font in fonts %}
        <li><div class="dropdown-item" style="font-family: '{{font.font_family}}'; text-align: center;">{{font.font_name}}</div></li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image of the error]

Further reading (from http://5.9.10.113/65685854/dropdown-button-in-bootstrap-5-not-working) has shown that a new version of Popper is actually causing the problem. So, I will investigate a little more and see what I can do.

### Edit for answer

Just for testing purposes, I added this snippet from Bootstrap's download page, and it works as expected. From here I went through all of my sources for bootstrap (not to mention that I folded and added the Popper CDN) and come to find out, something was wrong with my bootstrap.js file.

After grabbing the newest distribution of it from npm (and putting the build into a subdirectory for my use) I exchanged the Popper CDN for its counterpart via npm as well (I downloaded it, went into node_modules/ @popper/core/..., found the min file and referenced it) and now it works well. Last thing worth mentioning: **ONLY USE THE .MIN.* FILES!** so popper.min.js, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css... having all the other files in `script` tags will cause Bootstrap to not function properly.

```html
<html class="w-100 h-100">
<head>
    <title>
        Menu
    </title>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body class="m-0 p-0 w-100 h-100">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is completely wrong to insert all of those script tags. You should import the Bootstrap CSS file and the Bootstrap JS file (Bundle) **Only** and it should work and I would also note that [Bootstrap 5 don't need jQuery to work](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/javascript/#still-want-to-use-jquery-its-possible).

Comment: Yes. Which I had to begin with. I think there was something wrong with my bootstrap.js file - it might have been corrupted somehow, I don't know. It works now (with the setup you mentioned). Nice to know about jquery, however I think I'll keep it - it might be easier to do things with it than with clean javascript.

Comment: Kevin's comment should be considered as answer. For clarification in case of bootstrap 5 you have to remove popper and jQuery and use bootstrap.bundle.js.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I received this error (`TypeError: i.createPopper is not a function`) each time when popovers should be shown.  Previously I had to make use of the Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS (Option 2) - due to conflict with other scrips. However this is no longer necessary in my project, with Bootstrap 5.1.1.

Including only the Bootstrap bundle with popper - as per @Kevin's comment above - fixed the issue for me - And the previous conflicts don't seem to be an issue anymore. All popovers, tooltips, modals, sidebars etc. seem to now be working properly:

```
<body>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue now, as @Daniel said above, I'm using bootstrap.bundle.min.js instead of using Popper.js and Bootstrap.min.js files solved my problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to put this in the body as shown above.  Putting in head did not fix my pop-up issue.  The error stopped showing, but the popup was not showing either.  Putting in body has popup showing.

Comment: Yes, the fastest way to solve this is just adding the bootstrap.bundle.min.js file.

Answer (score 41):

For **angular** project make sure you have to use
 `"scripts": [ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ]`.

Answer (score 39):

I was including `bootstrap.min.js` instead of `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Comment: Basically the same here. Switched from bootstrap.js to bootstrap.bundle.js. Thanks, Jimmy.

Answer (score 9):

It happens because Bootstrap 5+ uses popper js for dropdown, and requires popper.js or popper.min.js to be declared in your script sources, or you can use bootstrap.bundle.js (or bootsrap.bundle.min.js).

So instead of just using:

```
<script src="[...YOUR_JS_CDN...]/bootstrap.min.js" />
```

Add popper js before bootstrap:

```
<script src="[...YOUR_JS_CDN...]/popper.min.js" />
<script src="[...YOUR_JS_CDN...]/bootstrap.min.js" />
```

Or use `bootstrap.bundle`:

```
<script src="[...YOUR_JS_CDN...]/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
```

In your case, replace this (since you redeclare bootstrap js again at the end):

```
<script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

And use only:

```
<script src="{% static 'Pages/Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I can now use submenus in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error in my ANGULAR 13 project & solve it after performing below changes:-

I changed the code in **angular.json** file like
build >> options >> scripts

```
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              
              "src/assets/js/popper.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/calender.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js",

              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
```

& use the specific version of BOOTRAP, JQUERY & POPPER JS in **package.json** file like:-

```
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
```

Comment: Open angular.json, find the "scripts" array. Remove `popper.min.js` and change `bootstrap.min.js` to `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

According to project Angular,  must be declared in the component where the navbar or function is called.
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';

Answer (score 1):

I am using bootstrap's icons as well and my angular.json currently works with this configuration:

```
"styles"[
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-cons.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
]
```

yup, only with those three imports my problem was solved, hope this can be usefull to someone else.

**This answer is based on the bootstrap docs which says:**

Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper. Popper isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 1):

From the Bootstrap documentation:

> You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

worked for by moving popper.js to src/assets/js/popper.min.js in angular 13

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and it was caused by the wrong order of js insertions.
First you have to load popper js then bootstrap js as written on bootstrap doc site. This solved this issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of not loading popper.js along with bootstrap.

**The bootstrap dropdown menu uses javascript code from popper js**. In order to work with the bootstrap menu, you must use popper.js.

You can use this **bootstrap starter file** in any kind of project whether it is Django or any other framework.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or you can add popper.js and bootstrap js before your ending body tag and don't forget to add popper js before bootstrap.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my Vue 3 and Nuxt-bridge app I added this to the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
script: [
      {
        src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      },
      {
        src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
        integrity: "sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ",
        crossorigin:"anonymous"

      }
]
```

And made sure I didn't have any versions of bootstrap or jquery in my package.json

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with popper.js and I just figured out to replace my cdn with  bootstrap js bundle to solve this issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32901631)

Comment: I could use the CDN, but for a local server with no connection to the internet, this would not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you did not install bootstrap then please firstly install bootstrap by `npm i bootstrap`
and then;

In Angular.json add following lines;

```
"scripts":["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"]
```

make sure you add `bootstrap.min.js` first.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.